# Reading NFC serial number with Titanium (Android)

Tags: android, titanium, nfc

I'm trying to use Titanium to read the NFC serial number of a small device. Unfortunately all I can find online is related to tag reading, but that's not what I want. Is there any way to do this? I need this unique serial number to retrive some data from a remote database.

Comment: How is reading the NFC serial number not reading the tag? Here is the [native android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/Tag.html#getId()) on doing it - I do not know if it will help you with Titanium.

Comment: If you want to read tagId then it is very random behaviour,I have tested it on native Java code as well,it is working some device and returns null on some other devices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am a complete Android newbie. My app should be quite simple: don't do anything until you read a TAG, and when you read it, use it to fetch some data once from a remote server. No menus buttons etc. Unfortunately I really don't know how to go about the first part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, easier than expected:

```
function handleTechDiscovery(data){
   //alert('TECH DISCOVERED:: ' + data.tag.id);
   connectToDatabase(data.tag.id); 
   //...
}
```